# Getting views from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, youtube-api

I'm fumbling through the YouTube API and I have gotten to where I have the code giving me this array(pictured from Chrome tools). It is the views for the last 30 days for a particular videoID. What I now need is to isolate just the views from the array. I ultimately want to sum them all up so I end up with just the total views for the video. I'm not sure how to loop through it or get a sum for the views. Any assistance is welcome.

[image: Results]

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have a 30 cells array of data, we imagine you named it `resultArray` and every view is placed in `resultArray[index][1]` so this is how we get total views of this video:

```
var totalViews = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
    var view = parseInt( resultArray[i][1] )
    if (!isNaN(view)) totalViews += view
}

console.log(totalViews) // You have the total views here
```

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` was born for calculating sum of an array.
I'm slicing by 1 to ignore the first header data.

```js
var data = [
  ["date", "sum"],
  ["date-1", 34],
  ["date-2", 42],
  ["date-3", 12],
  ["date-4", 3]
];

var result = data.slice(1).reduce((total, current) => total + current[1], 0);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var responseArr = [['total', 'views'], ['date', 3], ['date', 4]];

var totalViews = 0;
for(var i = 1; i < responseArr.length; i++) {
    var currentDayArr = responseArr[i];
    totalViews += currentDayArr[1];
}
```

Start at 1 to ignore the first array element that tells you what the columns are.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume that last30days is your array

```
var sum = 0;

last30days.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  if(index == 0) return;

  sum += element[1];
};
```